# Large list error filtering with indexed column SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, large-lists

I have a custom list that has over 24k items and utilizes lookup columns. We have indexed columns and have been working with filtering to allow different views to manage the list for a few months now. 
We are currently having issues with a personal view that filters based on an indexed choice column. This is a basic view with the default style, no grouping and no totals. The filter would not return more than 5,000 items, but we receive the good ole 'This view cannot be displayed....' error message. This was working a few weeks ago (before the list hit 20k items). 
Views that filter based on other indexed columns are still working without issue. 
I know I am missing something but I cannot put my finger on it, any advice on how to resolve this error and get this view working again would be greatly appreciated. 
Side Note-
I have access to change the list view threshold but this is not an option for the business.

Comment: was the Choice column has single value or multi values..?

Comment: It only allows for a single value to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

We  can add indexes on up to **20 columns** on a list or library. While you can add up to 20 indexes per list or library, it's recommended you add indexes to only to the most commonly used columns. Indexes add overhead to the data.

We can normally still add indexes to columns when you have fewer than **20,000 items** in your list or library.

Please check the total number of columns indexed and 
**Choice (single value)** is Supported Column Types and **Choice (multi-valued)** is  Unsupported Column Type

**Supported Column Types**

1. Single line of text
2. Choice (single value)
3. Number
4. Currency
5. Date and Time
6. Person or Group (single value)
7. Managed Metadata
8. Yes/No
9. Lookup

**Unsupported Column Types**

10. Multiple lines of text
11. Choice (multi-valued)
12. Calculated
13. Hyperlink or Picture
14. Custom Columns
15. Person or Group (multi-valued)
16. External data

please check the Office link [Add an index to a SharePoint column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-index-to-a-SharePoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0) for more details